# Is there a large precision library for C that handles irrational numbers?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I just compiled the MPIR library for visual studio and I found out it does not have trigonometric functions, nor root functions for floating point numbers.

The reason I need this, is because I need to do some calculations with transcendentals which have precision greater than 1000 digits.

If anyone could suggest a library which is capable of this and preferably works well with visual studio 2010, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the related software links on the [GNU MPFR homepage](http://www.mpfr.org/#free-sw).

In particular, [MAPM](http://www.tc.umn.edu/%7Eringx004/mapm-main.html) may do what you want:

> **MAPM: A Portable Arbitrary Precision Math Library in C**
>
> ...
>
> This library will perform the following functions to any desired precision level : SQRT, CBRT, SIN, COS, TAN, ARC-SIN, ARC-COS, ARC-TAN, ARC-TAN2, LOG, LOG10, EXP, POW, SINH, COSH, TANH, ARC-SINH, ARC-COSH, ARC-TANH, FLOOR, CEIL, GCD, LCM, and also FACTORIAL.

It sounds like it should work with Visual Studio:

> It has been tested under Linux (x86), FreeBSD, HP-UX, Sun Solaris, Venix, MAC OSX, DOS, and **Win 2000, NT, XP**
>
> ... with the following compilers ....
>
> o) Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 (32 bit) and Microsoft C 5.1, 8.00c (16 bit)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look a [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](http://gmplib.org/).

> **GMP** is a free library for *arbitrary precision arithmetic, operating on
>   signed integers, rational numbers, and floating point numbers*. There
>   is no practical limit to the precision except the ones implied by the
>   available memory in the machine GMP runs on. GMP has a rich set of
>   functions, and the functions have a regular interface. (..)

And you can find a **C#/.NET Wrapper** [here](http://gnumpnet.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the MPFR library. It can use MPIR and provides much more complete floating-point support. It's home page is http://www.mpfr.org/. A Visual Studio solution for it can be found at http://gladman.plushost.co.uk/oldsite/computing/gmp4win.php. I had to make a couple of tweaks but I'm able to build MPFR with MPIR successfully.